# sp_send_dbmail does not attach the file to the email

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
DECLARE

@ATTACH_FILE nvarchar (max),
@SQL varchar (max);

/* ============================================================== */  

-- add files to attach
    SET @ATTACH_FILE = N'\\C:\attach\file.txt';

SET @SQL = 'exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = ''ProfileMail'',
@recipients = ''my@mail.ru'',
@reply_to = ''my@mail.ru'',
@subject = ''subject mail'',
@body = ''body mail'',
@file_attachments='' '+ @ATTACH_FILE +' '' ';

-- send mail
    EXEC(@SQL);
```

**UPD** remove the two slashes SET @ATTACH_FILE = N'C:\attach\file.txt'; - the error persists

I receive an error: Invalid file attachment \C:\attach\file.txt (file is located on a sql server).
I do not understand what the problem is.

Comment: remove two back slashes of @ATTACH_FILE

Comment: Are you able to access file with address C:\attach\file.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is about `'//'` and `extra space` in attachment address.
**It will work now.**

```
declare @attach_file nvarchar(100),@sql varchar(max)
   SET @ATTACH_FILE = N'C:\attach\file.txt';

SET @SQL = 'exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = ''ProfileMail'',
@recipients = ''my@mail.ru'',
@reply_to = ''my@mail.ru'',
@subject = ''subject mail'',
@body = ''body mail'',
@file_attachments='+char(39)+@ATTACH_FILE+char(39);

-- send mail
   Exec(@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
SET @ATTACH_FILE = N'\\C:\attach\file.txt';
```

with this

```
SET @ATTACH_FILE = N'C:\attach\file.txt';
```

Answer (score 0):

As you specified that file is in Sql server.Find out the exact address of the file using below query.

```
SELECT name, physical_name AS current_file_location
   FROM sys.master_files
```

And use the address in your mail attachment.